# Vagrant VM and Dynamic DNS - Not Working

Tags: dns, vagrant, remote-access, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

Has anyone here configured access to a Vagrant VM through dynamic DNS? I've configured my router to point to the Vagrant VM public IP address configured in Vagrantfile, but can't access it from an external network. From other computers in LAN I can access the VM normally, but externally I can't.

Comment: whats the IP of your VM ? I guess you would need to give an IP from the subnet of your LAN so it can be visible from the router

Comment: The private IP address is: 192.168.33.x, the LAN subnet is 192.168.0.x. In Vagrantfile I setted the public IP address 192.168.0.xxx and I can access it from other computers in the LAN. In the router I've already done the forwarding to this public IP.

Comment: Just edited the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Just added the gateway IP from LAN router in the VM netvork interface that have the public IP address:

```
route add default gw myGatewayIp ethDevice
```